# python: scipy.spatial: draw a convex polygon and calculate the area

Tags: python, scipy, area, convex-hull

I am using python. Now I have some coordinates (earth plane coordinates) and I want to draw a convex polygon based on these coordinates. Besides, I need to save the polygon into a GeoJSON format and calculate the polygon area.

I heard that scipy.spatial can do this but I have no idea how to do that, besides, how to extract the polygon coordinates and calculate the area on earth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [scipy.spatial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html#module-scipy.spatial) does not include the functions you need.

[GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) would be suitable for this task. See for instance this [example](http://geopandas.org/user.html#examples) for calculating areas of a polynomial. It also allows to convert between different coordinates system and support output to GeoJSON format.